# search query that match the parameters exactly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Lets consider below table as an example

Table - subjects

```
ID     | subject
------ | ---------------
1      | maths, science
2      | maths, science, english
3      | english, computer
```

Query

```
SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE subject LIKE '%maths%' AND subject LIKE '%science%'
```

When  I run above query the out put would be as follows

```
ID     | subject
------ | ---------------
1      | maths, science
2      | maths, science, english
```

My question:

is it possible to modify above query to get the below result that match the search exactly to two parameters, even if the order of the search is changed 
i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE subject LIKE '%science%' AND subject LIKE '%maths%'
```

Desired result:

```
ID     | subject
------ | ---------------
1      | maths, science
```

Comment: `LIKE IN` - this operator does not exists in SQL Server, the query throws error.

Comment: @ Vojtěch Dohnal  sorry, I modified the query now.

Comment: I'd really modify my database design and not store values in a comma separated list. It will save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: @ Radu Gheorghiu i completely agree with you and I do understand what your talking about, but unfortunately for me I cannot modify the design of the real table at this point in my office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This database design is not good, use association table instead of comma separated list.

You can use LEN to check if there is anything else in the `subject` except the specified values.

```
SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE subject LIKE '%science%' AND subject LIKE '%maths%' 
                         AND LEN(subject) <= LEN('maths, science')
```

Comment: thank you! I believe this solves my problem. Let me run a test.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result by just using `CHARINDEX()` as it will check for both existence and you can enforce an order with it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM subjects 
WHERE CHARINDEX('maths', subject, 0) < CHARINDEX('science', subject, 0) -- enforces order
    AND CHARINDEX('maths', subject, 0) > 0 -- to make sure that your "first word" exists
```